# Why below mentioned query scans all the rows even if the indexing has created, query using "NOT IN" operator for checking values and subquery?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT col1 
FROM table1 
WHERE col2 BETWEEN '2023-01-15 00:00:00' AND '2023-01-15 07:31:09' 
AND col5 NOT IN('lit@yopmail.com','sneh@yopmail.com','snehah@yopmial.com','vishm@yopmail.com','aneha@yopmail.com','sneha10@yopmail.com','mukesh.sh@qa.team','ssw@yopmail.com','vish@yopmail.com','neuro@yopmail.com','delete@yopmail.com','sms@yopmail.com','krk@yopmail.com','samarora916@gmail.com','testing221@yopmail.com','om@yopmail.com','muskes@yopmail.com','putruuui@yopmail.com','rajuu@yopmail.com','priyan123@yopmail.com','prep28@yopmail.com','kewq@yopmail.com','ER.KUNALKHATRubbbhbh@GMAIL.COM') 
AND col4 IN (value1,value2) 
AND col3 > 2 
AND col1 IN (val1,val2,val3,val4,val5) 
AND orderID NOT IN (
    SELECT col6 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE col1 = value61 
    AND col4 IN (value1,value2) 
    AND col3 > 0 
    AND col2 BETWEEN '2023-01-15 00:00:00' AND '2023-01-15 07:31:09'
    );
```

And this the explain format = json of the query

```
"query_cost": "376074.60"
"table_name": "table1",
      "access_type": "ALL",
      "possible_keys": [
        "col5",
        "col1_col7_col3"
      ],
      "rows_examined_per_scan": 1663413,
      "rows_produced_per_join": 9300,
      "filtered": "0.56",
      "cost_info": {
        "read_cost": "374214.59",
        "eval_cost": "1860.01",
        "prefix_cost": "376074.60",
        "data_read_per_join": "99M"
"table": {
                  "table_name": "table1",
                  "access_type": "ref",
                  "possible_keys": [
                    "col6",
                    "col1_col7_col3"
                  ],
                  "key": "col1_col6_col3",
                  "used_key_parts": [
                    "col1"
                  ],
                  "key_length": "4",
                  "ref": [
                    "const"
                  ],
                  "rows_examined_per_scan": 63,
                  "rows_produced_per_join": 0,
                  "filtered": "0.74",
```

i created composite indexing for this query but it does't show any effect on this query So, I want to optimise this query by reducing the row scan and query cost of the query, please suggest something for this query.

I thing the problem is occur due to using not in where clause.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks and tidy up the question.

Comment: 'i created composite indexing for this query ' - did you -on what? it would be helpful if you published table definition as text..

Comment: Please edit your question to show (as text,not images) output of `show create table table1;`

Comment: How many rows satisfy the datetime criterion - `col2 BETWEEN '2023-01-15 00:00:00' AND '2023-01-15 07:31:09'`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.